# Get amount of components on final layout programmatically

Tags: presentation

I need to know how many components final layout has for each language programmatically. Is it any Sitecore API for it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done by parsing the layout XML for each field (renderings and final renderings). The key is to use `Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField.GetFieldValue` in order to obtain the XML value, otherwise you won't get the full XML with delta applied (final renderings --> shared renderings --> standard values).

In Sitecore PowerShell I was able to make it work with something like this:

```
$item = gi /sitecore/content/Home -Language 'en-US'

$sharedLayoutField = $item.Fields[[Sitecore.FieldIDs]::LayoutField]
$finalLayoutField = $item.Fields[[Sitecore.FieldIDs]::FinalLayoutField]

$sharedLayoutXml = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField]::GetFieldValue($sharedLayoutField)
$finalLayoutXml = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField]::GetFieldValue($finalLayoutField)

$sharedLayout = [Sitecore.Layouts.LayoutDefinition]::Parse($sharedLayoutXml)
$finalLayout = [Sitecore.Layouts.LayoutDefinition]::Parse($finalLayoutXml)

$sharedLayout.Devices[0].Renderings.Count
$finalLayout.Devices[0].Renderings.Count
```

In C#, something similar to this should do the trick.

```
// Returns the number of shared and final renderings for an item.
// Final renderings are based on language/version of item.
// This presumes there is only one device with renderings configured.
public static System.Tuple<int, int> CountRenderings(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
{
    var sharedRenderingsCount = CountRenderings(item, Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField);
    var finalRenderingCount = CountRenderings(item, Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField);
    return Tuple.Create(sharedRenderingsCount, finalRenderingCount);
}

private static int CountRenderings(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, Sitecore.Data.ID renderingFieldId)
{
    var field = item.Fields[renderingFieldId];
    var layoutXml = Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField.GetFieldValue(field);
    var layout = Sitecore.Layouts.LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutXml);
    var deviceLayout = layout.Devices[0] as Sitecore.Layouts.DeviceDefinition;
    return (deviceLayout?.Renderings.Count) ?? 0;
}
```

Of course, if you are using multiple devices, you will have to change the logic to pass in a device as parameter and return rendering count only for that device.

If you want to compare languages as well, you'll have to check the final renderings for each language variant.

Some reading:

- https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/editing-layout-details/
- https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/programmatically-update-layout-details-with-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get a list all the renderings by calling:

```
item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
```

Comment: Is it get just final layout rendering ? what if I need to know how many components on shared just for compare amount ?

Comment: how can I fetch Final Rendering using `item.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);` ?