# Fetching Final renderings in an .aspx page

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I am creating a script to fetch rendering parameters of a sublayout and edit data template item field data based on the values of fields of rendering parameters.

I was able to fetch renderings in .aspx page using the code
`Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference[] renderings = ProfileItemWithLanguage.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);`

But this is always giving me shared renderings. I have different data in different languages and need to fetch language specific data.

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this one:

```
var sharedRenderings = GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Item, Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField);
var finalRenderings = GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Item, Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField);


private static int GetRenderings(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, Sitecore.Data.ID renderingFieldId)
{
    var field = item.Fields[renderingFieldId];
    var layoutXml = Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField.GetFieldValue(field);
    var layout = Sitecore.Layouts.LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutXml);
    var deviceLayout = layout.Devices[0] as Sitecore.Layouts.DeviceDefinition;
    return deviceLayout != null ? deviceLayout.Renderings : null;
}
```

I used code from this answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/4956/277

Comment: This worked for me.
I got what the issue was. I had set default values in rendering parameters using standard values. Apparently, if you have not manually updated the rendering parameters, then `__Rendering` and  `__FinalRendering` fields remain empty (Even when they show default values). This was making the rendering fields data to not show up in the script.