# How to programmatically get or set only Shared Or Final Layout renderings

Tags: presentation

The following code will remove rendering from items. It works fine but the changes happen only in the `Shared Layout`.

Is there a way to read/update renderings in only a certain layout type -  `Shared` or `Final`.

```
LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(targetItem.Fields[FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
LayoutDefinition layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice("{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}");
DeviceDefinition ddef = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(deviceDefinition.ID.ToString());

/// Get the array of all renderings for the target page item                    
IEnumerable<RenderingDefinition> renderingsArray = ddef.Renderings.ToArray().Cast<RenderingDefinition>();  

ddef.Renderings = new ArrayList(renderingsArray.Where(r => r.ItemID != someRenderingId).ToList());

/// Save the layout changes                     
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
       targetItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
       layoutField.Value = layoutDefinition.ToXml();
       targetItem.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Comment: you just need to update the first line in your code for the final layout - `FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField` . LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(targetItem.Fields[FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField]);

Comment: Have you considered using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to do this work? There are commands for managing renderings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the final and shared layout using the following code. You can refer [Get amount of components on final layout programmatically](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/get-amount-of-components-on-final-layout-programmatically)

```
// Returns the number of shared and final renderings for an item.
// Final renderings are based on language/version of the item.
// This presumes there is only one device with renderings configured.
public static System.Tuple<int, int> CountRenderings(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
{
    var sharedRenderingsCount = CountRenderings(item, Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField);
    var finalRenderingCount = CountRenderings(item, Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField);
    return Tuple.Create(sharedRenderingsCount, finalRenderingCount);
}

private static int CountRenderings(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, Sitecore.Data.ID renderingFieldId)
{
    var field = item.Fields[renderingFieldId];
    var layoutXml = Sitecore.Data.Fields.LayoutField.GetFieldValue(field);
    var layout = Sitecore.Layouts.LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutXml);
    var deviceLayout = layout.Devices[0] as Sitecore.Layouts.DeviceDefinition;
    return (deviceLayout?.Renderings.Count) ?? 0;
}
```

And to set it again you can follow this - http://rockpapersitecore.com/2016/07/merging-final-renderings-back-down-into-shared-renderings/. You can modify code as per your requirements -

```
//Grab the field that contains the layout
    var layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);

    //Grab the field that contains the final layout
    var finalLayoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField]);

    if (layoutField == null)
        throw new Exception("Couldn't find layout on: {0}".FormatWith(item.Name));

    if (finalLayoutField == null)
        throw new Exception("Couldn't find final layout on: {0}".FormatWith(item.Name));

    //If we don't have a final layout delta, we're good!
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(finalLayoutField.Value))
    {
        return;
    }

    var finalLayoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(finalLayoutField.Value);

    using (new EditContext(item))
    {
        layoutField.Value = finalLayoutDefinition.ToXml();
        item.Fields["__Final Renderings"].Reset();
        item.Editing.AcceptChanges();
    }
```